# Getting 403 with POST method of Inbound Gateway - Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

So I have been trying to post some data to web service using Spring integration inbound gateway. GET method just works fine. So I tried to use POST, I'm passing some String. And trying to get a simple String as well. You can check the **TestService**. But everytime I try to run the Test case, I'm getting 403 error. I've checked Spring Security and every other aspect, but couldn't wrap my head around this. I googled for around 2 days but not a single clue about this.

You can look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880566/polling-http-serviceoutbound-gateway-process-using-transformer-in-spring-int) link, to see that my other functions which are GET methods and are working fine. I have this issue only with POST! So please help me out to know what is wrong with my code!

**My integration.xml is :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http">

<int:annotation-config/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json"/>
            <property name="favorParameter" value="true"/>
            <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="mediaTypes">
                <map>
                    <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.integration.samples.rest.json.view.ExtendedMappingJacksonJsonView" >
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jaxbJacksonObjectMapper"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<int:channel id="orderRequestChannel" />
<int:channel id="orderResponseChannel" />

<int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundOrderRequestGateway" 
    supported-methods="POST"
    request-channel="orderRequestChannel"
    reply-channel="orderResponseChannel"
    view-name="/order"
    path="/order/view"
    request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
    reply-timeout="50000">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator id="orderGatewayActivator"
                input-channel="orderRequestChannel"
                output-channel="orderResponseChannel"
                ref="testService" 
                method="createOrder" 
                requires-reply="true"
                send-timeout="60000" />  
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" context-path="org.springframework.integration.samples.rest.domain" />
<bean id="jaxbJacksonObjectMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.samples.rest.json.JaxbJacksonObjectMapper"/>
```

**Test Service Method is :**

```
@Service("testService")
public class TestService {

  public Message<String> createOrder(Message<String> orderRequest) {
    System.out.println("Inside!!!!!!!!!!");
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload("Some Response!").build();
  }
}
```

**Spring Security File :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<security:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" />

<!-- Configure Spring Security -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" realm="REST HTTP Web Service" create-session="never">
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:intercept-url pattern='/services/employee/*' access="hasRole('ROLE_REST_HTTP_USER')"  />
    <security:intercept-url pattern='/order/*' access="permitAll"  />
    <security:csrf disabled="true" />
</security:http>

<!--  In this example, we are using in memory authentication. The password encoder depends on
                Jasypt's String Digester to digest the password stored in users.properties -->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        <security:user-service properties="classpath:users.properties" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!--
    Use the StringDigester to create uni-directional password encryption.
    All uni-directional encryption methods supported in jasypt is integrated into
    Spring Security
-->
<bean id="jasyptStringDigester" class="org.jasypt.digest.StandardStringDigester" >
    <property name="algorithm" value="SHA-1" />
    <property name="iterations" value="100000" />
    <property name="saltGenerator">
        <bean id="zeroSaltGenerator" class="org.jasypt.salt.ZeroSaltGenerator"/>
    </property>
    <property name="saltSizeBytes" value="10"/>
</bean>

<!--
     This Spring Security-friendly PasswordEncoder implementation will
       wrap the StringDigester instance so that it can be used from
       the security framework.
   -->
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.jasypt.spring.security3.PasswordEncoder">
    <property name="stringDigester" ref="jasyptStringDigester"/>
</bean>
```

**Finally my test method :**

```
@Test
public void testPOST() throws Exception{
    final String fullUrl = "http://localhost:9080/rest-http/order/view";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<?> httpResponse = restTemplate.exchange(fullUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class, "Request");     
    //restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jsonHttpMessageConverter);
    if (!httpResponse.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)){
        logger.error("Problems with the request. Http status: " + httpResponse.getStatusCode());
    }

}
```

Please help me out guys!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to share DEBUG logs for `org.springframework` category from the server side when you hit your `POST` and get that `403 Forbidden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring's security then by default [CSRF protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) is enabled and a `X-Csrf-Token` is expected in the incoming request.

You have to disable this by adding below in your Spring security XML file. Read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html) about Spring's CSRF protection and below code is discussed in section $16.4.2 Configure CSRF Protection

```
<http>
    <!-- ... -->
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

Comment: I was so dumb and tired, I simply wrote what you wrote in your post, which means, I didn't disabled csrf. Once I make it as true, it worked. Thanks for the help bro!

Comment: No problems bro, it happens .. I hv also updated by answer to avoid any confusion ..